# How to expand this code for more than four 74hc165 shift registers? It works well with maximum four 74hc165 shift registers at a time

Tags: arduino-uno

```
#define NUMBER_OF_SHIFT_CHIPS   4
#define DATA_WIDTH   NUMBER_OF_SHIFT_CHIPS * 8

int LoadPin    = 9;
int EnablePin  = 8;
int DataPin    = 11;
int ClockPin   = 12;

unsigned long pinValues;
unsigned long oldPinValues;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(LoadPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(EnablePin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ClockPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DataPin, INPUT);

  digitalWrite(ClockPin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LoadPin, HIGH);

  pinValues = read_shift_regs();
  print_byte();
  oldPinValues = pinValues;
}

void loop()
{
  pinValues = read_shift_regs();
  if (pinValues != oldPinValues)
  {
    print_byte();
    oldPinValues = pinValues;
  }
}

unsigned long read_shift_regs()
{
  long bitVal;
  unsigned long bytesVal = 0;

  digitalWrite(EnablePin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(LoadPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  digitalWrite(LoadPin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(EnablePin, LOW);

  for (int i = 0; i < DATA_WIDTH; i++)
  {
    bitVal = digitalRead(DataPin);
    bytesVal |= (bitVal << ((DATA_WIDTH - 1) - i));

    digitalWrite(ClockPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(5);
    digitalWrite(ClockPin, LOW);
  }

  return (bytesVal);
}

void print_byte() {
  byte i;
  Serial.println("*Shift Register Values:*\r\n");

  for (byte i = 0; i <= DATA_WIDTH - 1; i++)
  {
    Serial.print(pinValues >> i & 1, BIN);

    Serial.print("  ");

  }
  Serial.print("\n");
  Serial.println(); Serial.println();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Arduino:SE.  Where did you get this version of the code?

Comment: possibly not a code problem

Comment: And what happens when you use more than 4 (by daisy chaining more shift registers and setting `NUMBER_OF_SHIFT_CHIPS` accordingly)? What is the actual problem description? What did you expect to happen and what actually did happen? What was the Serial output and the expected Serial output?

Comment: It looks like your `read_shift_regs()` function returns an `unsigned long` value, which consists of 32 bits. Each shift register reads back 8 bits, so with 4 of these shift registers you will fill all bits of a 32-bit unsigned long. If you attempt reading more than 4 registers, you will lose previously read bits. The solution is to make a function that can return more than 32 bits.

Comment: I would just add another shift register chain. A schematic would help understand better what you are doing.

Comment: After I put 'NUMBER_OF_SHIFT_CHIPS' as 5, the 1st shift register doesn't work but 5th one starts working. Also when I put  'NUMBER_OF_SHIFT_CHIPS' as 6 then 1st and 2nd shift registers don't work but rest four shift registers start working. So, I think @StarCat is right. What needs to be changed in this code?

Comment: You need to _understand_ the code to think on a solution. There are several possible solutions, but you should try the ones you _understand_. You may start by thinking how to "organize" more than 32 bits. As you found, an `unsigned long` cannot do this, perhaps an array of `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` is fine. -- We commonly don't give recommendations because that leads to opinion-based discussions, which are frowned upon.

Answer (score 3):

As StarCat mentioned in the comments, you return the read value as an `unsigned long`, which can hold exactly 4 bytes. When trying to write more into it with your current code you will loose the previous data. So you need a data structure that is able to hold all the data that you want to read.

I suggest that you do it like the `shiftIn()` function of the Arduino framework: Use a `DATA_WIDTH` of 8 bits (1 byte) and enclose the reading loop into another for loop, where you iterate over `NUMBER_OF_SHIFT_CHIPS`, getting exactly one byte from each chip and putting it into an array of `byte` (aka `uint8_t`). There are multiple ways to do this, but I will describe only one, not necessarily the best one for your situation.

First declare an array of `byte` on global scope. It needs to be `NUMBER_OF_SHIFT_CHIPS` bytes big. We initialize the data to zero:

```
byte shift_data[NUMBER_OF_SHIFT_CHIPS] = {0};
```

Set `DATA_WIDTH` to 8 bits:

```
#define DATA_WIDTH   8
```

Now look into `read_shift_regs()`. Enclose the for loop into another for loop iterating over `NUMBER_OF_SHIFT_CHIPS` and use that index to write the data into the corresponding byte in `shift_data` (by using `shift_data[j]` with the corresponding index `j`). As we write a global array we don't need to return anything, so you can make the function `void` (unless you want to return some other information).

```
void read_shift_regs()
{
  long bitVal;

  digitalWrite(EnablePin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(LoadPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  digitalWrite(LoadPin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(EnablePin, LOW);
  for(int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_SHIFT_CHIPS; j++){
    for (int i = 0; i < DATA_WIDTH; i++)
    {
      bitVal = digitalRead(DataPin);
      shift_data[j] |= (bitVal << ((DATA_WIDTH - 1) - i));

      digitalWrite(ClockPin, HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds(5);
      digitalWrite(ClockPin, LOW);
    }
  }
}
```

Then change all lines with

```
pinValues = read_shift_regs();
```

to
read_shift_regs();

And finally - to actually use the read values - you now need to access a complete array instead of a single variable. I will leave that to you. Basically its again just iterating over all elements of the array.

Note:

- I have not tested the above code in any way. Its more about explaining the principle.
- One can also handle the array with parameters, but if you don't know how to use arrays as parameters, then this can give you a lot of other errors. So I didn't suggest that.

Comment: using void before read_shift_regs() function gives error "void value not ignored as it ought to be". Which data type should I use here and why? Also, to print the output I use a for loop to return the shift_data[j] but output does not change.   P.S : I might be wrong here because i am new to arduino coding.

Comment: If you look at my implementation of the function you see that I don't use `return`. The functions doesn't need to return anything because the data is already globally a available in the array. And you get that error because you probably still have `pinValues = read_shift_regs();` somewhere. As I instructed you need to remove erything before the function call in that line (so no assignment with = )

Comment: What do you nean by "use a for loop to return shift_data[i]"? You can only return one time, not multiple times

Comment: If you look at above code in void loop, I have set if(pinValues!=oldpinValues) then the output bytes are printed for complete 8 x 8 matrix. I am not able to get the output here. Can you suggest a way to read values such that I can see them in Serial monitor? So, that I can take it as a reference for printing outputs.